# Is the set of consistent sentences recursive?

Tags: logic

Suppose we're dealing with a consistent axiomatizable extension of Enderton's arithmetic $T$ i.e. $Th(A_E) \subseteq T$ (as specified slide 5 [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall03/G22.3033-002/lec/lec11_h4.pdf)--note that I believe this has the same effect as considering any theory $T$ extending PA). Now consider the set $$\{ \# \sigma: T \cup \{\sigma \} \text{ is consistent} \}$$ Note that $\#$ is how we denote Godel number.

Is this set recursive, recusively enumerable, it's complement recursively enumerable, or neither?

I'm thinking it's recursive since for any $\sigma$ consistent with $T$ we are guaranteed to find a model of $T \cup \{\sigma\}$ and otherwise find a model of $T \cup \{\neg \sigma\}$. But what if $\sigma$ is independent of $T$--that is to say that neither $\sigma$ nor $\neg \sigma$ is inconsistent with $T$. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think "consistent" in your second-to-last sentence should be "**in**consistent."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple confusions here.

First of all, you write

> I believe this has the same effect as considering any theory T extending PA.

This is not true: most theories extending PA are *not* axiomatizable. Remember that "axiomatizable" means "has a *computable* set of axioms." We need the theory to be axiomatizable in order to get any good bound on the complexity of the set of sentences consistent with it.

Second of all, regarding your attempted argument: there is no good way to search (effectively) through potential models. Most structures are infinite, and even non-computable (that is, they have no computable "copies"), and plenty of consistent sentences have no computable models; and even ignoring that, the question of whether an infinite structure satisfies a given sentence is generally not recursively answerable. *(Incidentally, we can search through **finite** models and check satisfiability effectively, and so the set of sentences true in some finite model is indeed recursively enumerable, but that's quite different - this, together with the failure of compactness in the finite realm, is the first indicator that [finite model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_model_theory) might be quite different from general model theory, and this is further buttressed by [Trakhtenbrot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trakhtenbrot%27s_theorem).)* So that argument doesn't work.

So what about the answer?

Well, the first observation is that proofs from $T$ are finite (and recognizable, assuming $T$ is axiomatizable) objects, and so we *can* effectively search through them, so this tells us that the set of $T$-provable sentences is c.e. Since $\varphi$ is consistent with $T$ iff $T$ doesn't prove $\neg\varphi$, this tells us that the set of $T$-consistent sentences is *co*-r.e.

To show that the set of $T$-consistent sentences is not r.e., it's enough to show that it's not *recursive* (since r.e. and co-r.e. implies recursive). A set is recursive iff its complement is, so all we need to do is:

> Prove that if $T$ is a consistent axiomatizable theory extending PA, the set of consequences of $T$ is not recursive.

This is a consequence of (the strong form of) Godel's incompleteness theorem, and is a good exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The set of $T$-consistent sentences 
$$\{\#\phi : T \not \vdash \phi \to \bot\}$$
is certainly co-r.e., because you can enumerate sentences that lead to a proof of inconsistency.

The set of $T$-consistent sentences cannot be computable, because we could use it as an oracle to make a complete extension of $T$, and no such extension can be computable by the incompleteness theorem. Essentially, we make the extension by numbering the entire set of sentences $(\phi_i)$, and then at stage $i$ we place $\phi_i$ in our completion if it is consistent with $T$ and the finite set of sentences chosen at previous stages.   This forms the rightmost path in the tree of completions of $T$.

Putting these together, the set of consistent sentences is co-r.e. but not r.e.

The error in the argument of the post is that, because models of $T$ are infinite, and their satisfaction relations are not computable, we cannot search for models that validate $T + \phi$.